# how can I access the data from the class constructor which I have given some values. to another variable

Tags: flutter, dart

> here I want branchData = [ Branch(**branch: 'MEC' <----- this value**,year: const [1,2,3,4])]
>
> as my value to CourseData = [ Course(subject:null,branch: **here I need the above branch value**,year:null

````
import '../models/branch.dart';
import '../models/course.dart';

class CourseData {
  final branchData = [
    Branch(branch: 'MEC', year: const [1, 2, 3, 4]),
    Branch(branch: 'ECE', year: const [1, 2, 3, 4]),
    Branch(branch: 'CSE', year: const [1, 2, 3, 4]),
    Branch(branch: 'EEE', year: const [1, 2, 3, 4]),
    Branch(branch: 'CIV', year: const [1, 2, 3, 4]),
  ];
  final courseData = [
    Course(subject: null, branch: null, year: null),
  ];
}```
````

Comment: Since `branchData` is a list you can access it by `index`. Like `branchData[0]`. This will give you the first element in the list. You can access the properties using dot operator like `branchData[0].branch` this will give you **'MEC'**.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main(){

  NewClass instance = NewClass(fromConstructor: 'string that was passed');

  print(instance.newVariable);

}


class NewClass {

  final String fromConstructor;
  String newVariable;

  NewClass({this.fromConstructor}){

   newVariable = fromConstructor;
  }


}
```

From what I can understand, you are trying to get a value from your constructor and pass it to a second variable. You can do this through a constructor function.

Comment: No that did not work I already created a list of Branch which is a class, and given the data some values... now from that valued i want to use branchDate which is a list of Branch to get the values inside the Branch and pass it to courseData.....

Comment: Otherwise, I just need how can I get the course value in branchData[1].